# TextureProgressBar's progress_texture Doesn't Advance When Its value is Changed

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I am working in Godot 4.0, and having issues with the TextureProgressBar. In order to recreate this issue, make a new project, create a new scene as a Node2D, and add the children Timer and CanvasLayer. Then give the CanvasLayer its own child, a TextureProgressBar. Add a gdscript file to the Node2D and connect the Timer's timeout() signal to it (I changed the name of the timer to StartTimer, the CanvasLayer to Loading Screen, and the TextureProgressBar to Loading Bar, which is why the func call name is different in the provided code). Then replace the code in the script file with this:

```
extends Node2D

func _ready():
    get_node("Loading Screen/Loading Bar").position = Vector2(200, 360)
    get_node("Loading Screen/Loading Bar").set_value(1)

func start_world_creation():
    start_progress_bar()

func start_progress_bar():
    for x in 100:
        for y in 100:
            for time_waster in range(20000):
                time_waster += 300
        get_node("Loading Screen/Loading Bar").value += 1
        print(get_node("Loading Screen/Loading Bar").value)

func _process(delta):
    pass


func _on_start_timer_timeout():
    start_world_creation()
```

Finally, assign the images below to their respective places for the TextureProgressBar:
[image: Under Texture]
[image: Progress Texture]
[image: Over Texture]

For some reason, the TextureProgressBar does not update until its value reaches 100. Why is this, and how can I fix it? According to the documentation, it should update with every integer increase in value, since the TextureProgressBar's step value is set to 1, and max_value is 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the signal of the `Timer` is emitted and this code will run before the next frame:

```
func _on_start_timer_timeout():
    start_world_creation()
```

Which is calling this code which will finish before the next frame:

```
func start_world_creation():
    start_progress_bar()
```

Which is calling this code which will finish before the next frame:

```
func start_progress_bar():
    for x in 100:
        for y in 100:
            for time_waster in range(20000):
                time_waster += 300
        get_node("Loading Screen/Loading Bar").value += 1
        print(get_node("Loading Screen/Loading Bar").value)
```

So when Godot finally gets around to the next frame, the `value` of the `TextureProgressBar` is at `100.0`, which is also the default `max_value`, so you see it full.

Hopefully you can see the issue: The `time_waster` et.al. is keeping the thread busy, so Godot cannot do other stuff. *In this situation using `set_deferred` or `call_deferred` won't help you.*

---

The easier solution is to `await` a frame:

```
func start_progress_bar():
    for x in 100:
        for y in 100:
            for time_waster in range(20000):
                time_waster += 300
        get_node("Loading Screen/Loading Bar").value += 1
        print(get_node("Loading Screen/Loading Bar").value)
        await get_tree().process_frame
```

When the execution reaches `await`, Godot will save where it was, and continue after the specified signal (`get_tree().process_frame` in this case) is emitted.

---

Another thing you could do is run the code in another `Thread`. *In this case you can use `set_deferred` or `call_deferred` to manipulate the UI.*

---

If the `time_waster` et.al. code is an stand-in for some asynchronous operation, you might also want to look for an appropriate signal (or make one) so you can `await` until the asynchronous operation is completed.

---

**WARNING**: Using `await` has drawbacks: It cannot be cancelled or disconnected.

Thus:

- Even if you know the signal will never be emitted, you cannot make Godot forget.
- If the `object` was freed, and the signal is emitted, you have a runtime error.

If you run into that, refactor the code by connecting a `Callable` continuation (which can be an anonymous method a.k.a. "lambda") to the signal... When the object is freed, Godot will disconnect it.

*If you need to check if a `Node` is about to be freed by `queue_free`, you can check `is_queued_for_deletion`. If you need to check if you have a reference to a `Node` that was freed, use `is_instance_valid`. If you need to do something before an `Object` is freed, have it override `_notification` and react to `NOTIFICATION_PREDELETE`.*